# Google Maps highlight nearby by distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using the Google Maps, how is it possible by JS to mark an area by distance or time.

For eg, if location is Delhi and I want to **highlight** on the map an area 2 to 3 hours surrounding Delhi from the center or outskirts, or maybe by distance like 30 to 40 km.

Google maps has a nearby tab but it asks you to search rather than provide filters.

How can such a thing be accomplished?

Comment: Are you asking how to display a circle with a radius of 30 or 40 km on your map?

Comment: Yes, circle. By distance and by time. I am trying to find a suitable function for time from the documentation. Couldn't find as of now.

Comment: You can only define a circle by distance in meters.  For time, you need to make an assumption of the speed and calculate the distance from that.

Comment: I would have one solution using distance but only if you are using `NodeJS` in your back-end and `MongoDB`. Would you actually be interested?

Answer (score 0):

This has been done a few times, so it's definitely possible. Search for **Isochronic** Maps, and have a look at implementations like [Cartoo](http://cartoo.dyndns.org/)